# Does Spark Kubernetes suport the --py-files argument?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I'm trying to run a PySpark Job using Kubernetes. Both the main script and the py-files are hosted on Google Cloud storage.
If I launch the Job using the standalone resource manager:

```
spark-submit \
--master local \
--deploy-mode client \
--repositories "http://central.maven.org/maven2/" \
--packages "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.2" \
--py-files https://storage.googleapis.com/foo/some_dependencies.zip \
https://storage.googleapis.com/foo/script.py some args
```

It works fine.
But if I try the same using Kubernetes:

```
spark-submit \
--master k8s://https://xx.xx.xx.xx  \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=gcr.io/my-spark-image \
--repositories "http://central.maven.org/maven2/" \
--packages "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.2" \
--py-files https://storage.googleapis.com/foo/some_dependencies.zip \
https://storage.googleapis.com/foo/script.py  some args
```

Then the main script runs, but it can't find the modules in the dependencies files.
I know I can copy all the files inside the Docker image but I would prefer doing it this way.

Is this possible? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: What you are asking seems possible, as you can read from the documentation:
https://apache-spark-on-k8s.github.io/userdocs/running-on-kubernetes.html#python-support
At this point I would wonder if the cluster can access the dependencies.zip file?

Comment: @PjoterS Yes the dependencies are all publicly accessible. When I run this same spark-submit using a Yarn cluster everything works fine.

Comment: Hello @Pablo, How about keeping the dependencies local ( as shown in the documentation local:///) ? Could be this an option for you?

Comment: Hi @PjoterS it would be my last option. The problem with that is that every time you update a dependency you have to rebuild the Docker images which is not convenient in my case.

Comment: Hello @Pablo, can you get access to the shell into the running Container `kubectl exec -it shell-demo -- /bin/bash` and wget your dependencies hosted on google storage?

Comment: have you been able to try steps from my previous comment?

Answer (score 1):

So the idea behind the k8s scheduler is to put absolutely everything in the container.

So your CI/CD would build a Dockerfile with the Apache Spark kubernetes Docker as its base and then have a zipped copy of your python repo and driver python script inside the docker image. Like this:

```
$ bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://<k8s-apiserver-host>:<k8s-apiserver-port> \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --py-files local:///path/to/repo/in/container/pyspark-repo.zip \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=pyspark-repo-docker-image:1.0.0 \
    local:///path/to/repo/in/container/pyspark-driver.py
```

Your `spark.kubernetes.container.image` should be your full application complete with a

- zip of the repo for `--py-files` (ex: repo.zip)
- your `requirements.txt` installed to the container's version of python (done in your repo's Dockerfile)
- driver script (ex: driver.py)

Answer (score 0):

Actually `--py-files` can be used to distribute dependencies to executors. Can you display the errors you get ? Do you import your zips (`SparkContext.addPyFile`) in the main .py ?

Comment: I'm not getting any Spark related errors. Just the main script not being able to find the dependencies from the PyFiles modules. 
Weird thing, I just notice that I'm not getting the error if I use deploy-mode=client instead of cluster. Is that a requirement for using pyfiles in k8s?

pd: yes I'm importing the zip file in my main script.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I don't think files in --py-files will be distributed to driver and executors.

Answer (score 0):

ENV:
spark 2.4.3

UPDATED answer:

In https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#dependency-management, docs says:

> Note that using application dependencies from the submission client’s local file system is currently not yet supported.

OLDER answer:

I am facing the same issue. I don't think files in --py-files will be distributed to driver and executors. 
I submit a python file to K8s cluster with following command:

```sh
bin/spark-submit \
--master k8s://https://1.1.1.1:6443 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name spark-test \
--conf xxx.com/spark-py:v2.4.3 \
--py-files /xxx/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/spark_test1.py \
http://example.com/spark/__main__.py
```

I got logs in driver pod:

```
+ PYTHONPATH='/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-*.zip:file:///xxx/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/spark_test1.py'
```

I got errors like following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/spark-5e76171d-c5a7-49c6-acd2-f48fdaeeb62a/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from spark_test1 import main
ImportError: No module named spark_test1
```

From the errors, the main python file is get uploaded and distributed to driver. For --py-files, PYTHONPATH contains an exact same path in my cmd which I don't think those files get uploaded to that path in driver pod and executor pod.

I tried to replace the `spark_test1.py` from a local path to a HTTP URL. The PYTHONPATH changed accrodingly, but the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I mount pvc to the container by `persistentVolumeClaim`
and before submit the spark application, download the -py-files to the pv(like glusterfs) first, the `spark on k8s` will not downlod it for you,

and `spark on yarn` driver and exector will do download files for you with `spark.yarn.archive` param

```
sh bin/spark-submit  \
--master k8s://https://xxx:6443  \
--deploy-mode cluster  \
--conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=xxx/spark:latest   \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Always \
--conf spark.eventLog.dir=/xxx/spark-eventlog \
--conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true \
--conf spark.executor.instances=1  \
--conf spark.executor.memory=1024m \
--conf spark.driver.memory=1024m \
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.request.cores=1 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.request.cores=1 \
--name spark-demo  \
--py-files local:///xxx/spark_utils.zip \
/xxx/pyspark_demo.py
```

as I tested with spark-2.4.8 with hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.16.1
the `--py-files` is working ,it pass to the `PYTHONPATH`

and in the Dockerfile

```
ENV PYTHONPATH ${SPARK_HOME}/python/lib/pyspark.zip:${SPARK_HOME}/python/lib/py4j-*.zip
```

so generated spark-submit like this

```sh
'PYTHONPATH': '/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:/opt/spark/jars/spark-core_2.11-2.4.8.jar:/opt/spark/python/lib
/pyspark.zip:/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-*.zip:file:/xxx/spark_utils.zip',
```